# Why using IntPtr for handle?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, c++-cli, window-handles

When using PInvoke, I noticed that we need to use `IntPtr` to refer to Windows handles. I am wondering why not just use `int` for the handle? My understanding of a handle is that it is just an integer value.

Comment: Your making the most common mistake that causes x64 incompatibilities.

Comment: Sure, they're integer values. But no one said they have to be 32 bits...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A windows handle is defined as *an integer of the native machine pointer size*. That's so that they can secretly be a pointer if they need to be. (A handle probably *is not a pointer*, but it is *permitted* to be one if the operating system implementers deem it necessary. They typically are not actually pointers for security reasons; it makes it too easy for people to abuse the system if they are actually pointers.)

An int in C# defined as a 32 bit integer, which will be too small on a 64 bit machine.  An IntPtr is defined as an integer that can hold a pointer of the machine size. That's why you always use IntPtr when interoperating with handles.

Answer (score 10):

Handles are *pointer-sized* values.

They're 8 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I'd say "pointer-*sized*" instead of "pointer" (even though I guess in the strict C/C++ sense, that isn't too accurate, since handles are `typedef`'d as a pointer all right, and `size_t` isn't necessarily the size of a pointer)... but if they're indices into a table, chances are they're used as integers. But yeah, point taken.

Answer (score 4):

The size of a handle is dependant on the machine architecture (32/64 bit). `IntPtr` will take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

A handle is essentially a system level pointer, and a pointer does not implicitly cast to an int.  It is a type by itself.  So that's why you have `IntPtr` in .NET to represent the Handle type.